# How to change the qubits of a cirq Circuit?

Tags: cirq, quantum-circuit

I am constructing generic circuits, and I would like to change the qubits after creating the circuits. Is there a way in cirq to do so?
for instance:

```
circuit = cirq.Circuit(cirq.X.on(cirq.GridQubit(0, 1)))
```

and I would like this circuit to be transformed into:

```
cirq.Circuit(cirq.X.on(cirq.GridQubit(5, 7)))
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the qubit, there is a method associated with the circuit object that allow you to change the qubits:

```
circuit = cirq.Circuit(cirq.X.on(cirq.GridQubit(0, 1)))

# transforming the qubits
qubit_map =  {cirq.GridQubit(0, 1): cirq.GridQubit(5, 7)}
circuit = circuit.transform_qubits(qubit_map =qubit_map)
```

will return the circuit where only the qubits are changed:

```
cirq.Circuit(cirq.X.on(cirq.GridQubit(5, 7)))
```